# Node Express: axios shows Request failed with status code 404, even if the request was completed(failed to redirect)

Tags: node.js, express, axios, request

I am using axios to send a post / put request to a Express route.
**put**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

        const body = {
            title: data.get('title'),
            description: data.get('description'),
        };

        await axios.put(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST}/view/${_id}`, body)
    };
    //example link: http://localhost:3000/view/61e038051b755034d31d49a2
```

**put** route

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) =>
{
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Declaration.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body)
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

**post**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

        const body = {
            title: data.get('title'),
            description: data.get('description'),
        };

        await axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST, body)
    };
```

**post** route

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) =>
{
    const declaration = new Declaration({ ...req.body })
    await declaration.save();
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

Now, when submitting to the **put** form, It displays this error: **Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Request failed with status code 404**, but the request was actually cmopleted and the model saved, even if the redirect never happened and the error page remained. When submitting to the **post** form, **No Error**, and similar to the first, the request was completed but no redirect, and the form page remains the same. **So how can I fix this?**

Comment: The first thing to say is that `axios()` calls from within web page Javascript do NOT redirect the browser web page itself.  They return the 302 response to your Javascript and it's up to your Javascript for whether it wants to set `window.location` to the new location or not.

Comment: Is your PUT request handler really registered for `/view/61e038051b755034d31d49a2`?  All you show is `/:id` so we don't know if the `/view` part is in there at some higher level or not?

Comment: @jfriend00 server.use('/view', view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **axios**

```
  await axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST, body)
        .then((res) =>
        {
            window.location = res.request.responseURL;
        })
```